# Dynamically assign rowClasses attribute on <apex:dataTable> component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, css

I have a VisualForce page that render into a PDF file with the following component declaration:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!someSObjectList}" var="SObj"
  rowClasses="{!IF( MOD( pos, 2 ) == 0, "grey_box,white_box", "white_box,grey_box" )}">
  .
  .  [column declarations]
  .
</apex:dataTable>
```

However, I cannot get it to compile. Attempting to save prompts the following error message:

> Save error: The element type "apex:dataTable" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:dataTable>".

How can I accomplish this (i.e. get zebra patterning with context-dependant first colour)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the compiler is upset by your using double quotes inside your double quotes
where you have:

```
rowClasses="{!IF( MOD( pos, 2 ) == 0, "grey_box,white_box", "white_box,grey_box" )}"
```

try:

```
rowClasses="{!IF( MOD( pos, 2 ) == 0, 'grey_box,white_box', 'white_box,grey_box' )}"
```

Comment: As using single class tags between double quotations used to work, it didn't occur to me that this might be the problem. 
This looks like some VF inconsistency.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Glad it helped you out :)